# Can't get Access Token

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, python

Per the documentation, I've created an "installed package" in the admin panel of SFMC, which provides me a `clientId` and `clientSecret`.  I'm using the Python `requests` library to make the call from my command line.  This is *just* to get an `accessToken`, so the code is pretty straightforward:

```
import requests

url = 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
clientId = '123'
clientSecret = 'abc'

response = requests.request('POST', url,
                            headers=headers,
                            auth=(clientId, clientSecret),
                            verify=False)

print(response.text)
```

The `verify` flag is set to `False` for now because of unresolved issues with the Python package `certifi`, but this is a separate issue and shouldn't affect the request.

I don't know exactly what the issue is, but I always receive this error message:

```
{"message":"clientId is required","errorcode":10002,"documentation":""}
```

I'm supplying the clientId in the appropriate (Python) syntax, and it's such a simple request that I can't see why it's failing.  Any help is much appreciated.

**SFMC API documentation:** https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/mc-dev-setup.htm

**Requests (Python HTTP library)**: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Have you tried using the clientId and clientSecret in just Postman, or some other REST tool?

Comment: I just downloaded Postman for Windows (x64) and it worked, but only after I turned off SSL certificate verification (this is a separate issue I'm having with the 'Request' library, but I don't think it's related).  In any case, I'm still not sure why making the Python request is resulting in an error.

Comment: I was able to duplicate this error by setting Content-Type to text instead of application/json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to send the clientId and clientSecret as the body of the POST not as an auth header like:

```
{
  "clientId": "gyjzvytv7ukqtfn3x2qdyfsn",
  "clientSecret": "************"
}
```

or a data key value pair like: `data = {'clientId':'value'}`

Comment: I tried this but received a different error: 

`{"documentation": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm",
"errorcode": 0,
"message": "Bad Request"}`.

I assume that this means the request validated (i.e., credentials were supplied in the correct format), but the credentials themselves were incorrect.  I copied/pasted the clientId and clientSecret directly from SFMC into my script, so I'm certain that they're correct.

Comment: It occurred to me that, in addition to removing the `auth` header, I should try removing the `headers` header as well.  This did the trick!  I'm not really sure exactly why this is, but it solved the issue.  Thanks for the tip @TravisNaughton.